# Awfully large screenshots; is there anything to do about this?

Tags: windows-11, screenshot, scaling, snipping-tool

My new laptop has half-4K display. In order to look "usable" Windows 11 suggests 300% scaling on all elements. Most UI elements looks just fine, but Snipping Tool is not able to recognize this fact and thus captures enormously large screenshots.

For example, this is a screenshot that I captured on my new laptop (1800 x 740 px):

[image]

And this is nearly the same area captured on my old PC (979 x 433):

[image]

Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Thanks for the advices. I am already doing so (the IrfanView way). With this question I was wondering, if there is anything in the Snipping tool or Windows settings to work-around this problem. Thank you.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Consider adding this as an answer. That this is a normal behaviour and nothing really could be changed except for using 3rd party software as you described in your comment.

Comment: Thanks, @trejder... moved to a more complete answer.

Comment: It's normal because the 300% scaling is _not_ just raw pixel scaling from 1x1 to 3x3 – it's just all the elements that become larger, but they still make full use of the individual pixels, e.g. fonts are rendered in finer detail. So if the screenshot tool was to "recognize" scaling and shrink the image down, it would lose information, and the screenshot would still look bad if someone else on a 4K screen had to zoom it back in to 300% for viewing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be no native way using the MS Snipping Tool. However there are two work-arounds.

1. Try a [third-party screenshot tool](https://geekflare.com/screenshot-tools-for-windows/) -- there are many, such as [Greenshot](https://getgreenshot.org/) or [these others](https://alternativeto.net/software/greenshot/?platform=windows), and one might work as you want, or
2. Edit the screenshot in a tool such as free [IrfanView](https://www.irfanview.com/) or one of [many alternative image editors](https://www.irfanview.com/), and set the desired resolution (resize via Ctrl-R, in *IrfanView*) and compression, if JPEG. This has the advantage of allowing cropping, adding text and other editing operations, so I use an image editor by default.

[image]

Comment: IrfanView also has a nice batch feature; if you have many images to process, you can have it handle them all at one time and still specify, for example, all of the options in the dialog box above.